# how to run node/ razzle build within dockerfile and docker-compose in noninteractive mode? to avoid prompt?

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, non-interactive, razzle

I dockerize a web application using docker-compose.
So, I am using containers / services for "**node**", "**traefik**" and "**db**" (postgres db) within my **docker-compose YAML file**.

In my Dockerfile for "**node**" I want to finally build the production build and start the node server.

By using `RUN npm run-script build`, the razzle production build should be started to run. (in package.json for scripts-->build is set "razzle build".

My issue is that I wish to have everything automated, without providing responses on the command line manually after docker-compose up.

When I start the production build manually, I have to type **"Y"** to start it finally:

```
> razzle build

? This runs the production build, are you sure you want to run it? Add --noninteractive to remove this prompt. (Y/n)
```

And I got the following error after execution docker-compose build ...

```
> razzle build

? This runs the production build, are you sure you want to run it? Add
--noninteractive to remove this prompt. (Y/n) ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run-script build -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

But how can I realize this automatically in the dockerfile?

I already tried:

Using -y flag:
`RUN npm run-script build -y`

Using echo for providing the permission:
`RUN npm run-script build -y`
`RUN ["echo", "'Y'"]`

Or tried to change the session into noninteractive
`ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

but it did not work

Does anybody has a nice idea how to fix it in my dockerfile?

thanks in advance